# Pythagorean triple with list

Tags: python

```
num_list = [(20, 99, 101),
            (60, 91, 109),
            (16, 112, 113),
            (44, 117, 125)]
```

Three numbers a, b, c, are called Pythagorean triple if a2 + b2 = c2 . Make a lambda function called is_pythagorean_triple that accepts three arguments. It returns the value True if it is a pythagorean triple. Otherwise, it is  False. By using that function and the provided list, print the following:

```
(20, 99, 101) is a triple Pythagoras.
(60, 91, 109) is a triple Pythagoras.
(16, 112, 113) is not a triple Pythagoras.
(44, 117, 125) is a triple Pythagoras.
```

Hint: To get the first element in the first triple, you can write num_list[0][0]

My code is a little bit mistakes like below:

```
is_pythagorean_triple = lambda a, b, c : a **2 + b**2 == c**2
print(is_pythagorean_triple(5, 6, 2))
print(is_pythagorean_triple(20, 99, 101))
```

the first print can get false and the second one is True
I want to know how to use the num_list[0][0] so that I can use that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific element of your list, you can pass the values to the method like this

```
print(is_pythagorean_triple(num_list[0][0], num_list[0][1], num_list[0][2]))

# Or flatten values like this
print(is_pythagorean_triple(*num_list[0]))
```

---

You may iterate on your list to test for all

```
for x, y, z in num_list:
    print(x, y, z, is_pythagorean_triple(x, y, z))

for coord in num_list:
    print(coord, is_pythagorean_triple(*coord))
```

Get expected output

```
for coords in num_list:
    if is_pythagorean_triple(*coords):
        print(coords, "is a triple Pythagoras.")
    else:
        print(coords, "is not a triple Pythagoras.")
```

---

You `lambda` is correct, it's the same as the following. It takes argument named `a, b, c` and return a bool result, then you provide values from `num_list`

```
def is_pythagorean_triple(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> bool:
    return (a ** 2 + b ** 2) == c ** 2
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to define 'is_pythagorean_triple' ? I used a b c but that's wrong...

Comment: is_pythagorean_triple = num_list[0][0], num_list[0][1], num_list[0][2] : num_list[0][0]**2 + num_list[0][1]**2 = num_list[0][2]**2

Comment: Because the error happened ,without the define of is_pythagorean_triple...

Comment: @ssssmaner no no, the method is GENERIC, it takes values and do something, then you PROVIDE him values from your list, see my edit

Comment: Yes. You are right! my define is right. and the out put is :(20, 99, 101) True
(60, 91, 109) True
(16, 112, 113) False
(44, 117, 125) True

Comment: but how to add a if statement in for coord in num_list:?

Comment: @ssssmaner it seems you may learn more python, before trying to achieve some stuff, read and do some tutorials ;) see my edit for the `if` you expect

Comment: You are the best and I learned coords as well. Thank you sooooo much!